# Nucleo-32 L432KC doesn't work properly when powered by the 5v pin

Tags: arduino, nucleo, stm

I uploaded the simplest code to my Nucleo-32 L432KC STM32 board. The LED3 should just blink every 1 second.
It works perfectly when the board is connected to the computer by USB, and it also works perfectly when the power source is connected to the VIN pin, although in that case it consumes about 40mA which is unacceptable for that project.

I'm tying to move the power source positive pin to 3V3 or to 5V but in both cases the board doesn't function properly. It does get power and starts working, lighting up the LED2 red light, but the LD3 light that should blink just does't light up.
And that's just the example. obviously my original code doesn't work as well when the board is connected to 3V3 or 5V.

Is anyone familiar with this issue?

Comment: If you measure VDD, does it measure 3.3V?

Comment: Yes, it measures 3.33V

Comment: Have you tried a hard reset?

Comment: What do you mean by hard reset? I shutting down the power and turning it back on, and also tried to use the reset button of the L432KC